# Simulating linear motion of object

Tags: physics

I would like to calculate the distance travelled of an object.  I have a start position(mm), an acceleration (mm/s^2), a speed (mm/s) and then a deceleration (mm/s^2).  Note the deceleration value can differ from the acceleration.  There is also a delay time in seconds

For each frame of time (currently 30 fps) I need to calculate how far the object will have travelled taking into account the initial delay and potentially the object never reaching full speed before slowing again.

I am currently working with:

Time = Seconds Elapsed and not frames

DistanceTravelled = (Speed * (Time - Delay) + (Acceleration * (Time -Delay) ^ 1 / 2))                         + ((Deceleration * (Time - Delay) ^ 1 / 2))

but this appears wrong but why?

Answer (score 1):

Deceleration is the result of a force directed opposite the motion. Therefore, the deceleration term should be *subtracted*, not *added*. If you do this, the formula will be correct assuming that

1. the object sits for time `Delay`, and then
2. acquires initial `Speed` and is immediately subjected to both `Acceleration` and `Deceleration`

If the above is not what you had in mind (e.g., if you meant a period of acceleration followed by a period of deceleration), please clarify the question.